# android modo depuracion mantener la configuracion?

Tags: android, adb, samsung

Queria saber como puedo mantener una modificacion que le haya hecho al dispositivo atravez del modo depuracion con adb (platform-tools) despues de reiniciarlo?

"Cuando aplico la modificacion si el dispositivo se apaga y vuelve a encender pierde la modificacion hay alguna manera de mantenero sin tener que estar haciendo siempre?"

es un movil samsung y quiero mantener los leds de camara y audio desactivados, pero cuando se reinicia vuelve y apararece

Comment: ¿Qué es latform-tools? ¿Cuál es la modificación?, recuerda agregar información que ayude a la comunidad saber que es lo que necesitas, ver [ask].

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools?hl=es-419, es la plataforma de sdk de android estoy intentando quitar los iconos de camara y microfono cuando estan encendidos, pero cuando se reinicia el movil vuelve y aparecen